# Cannot call parent class methods in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement an EventEmitter class which would be used to emit events between MVC components. I am fairly new to JavaScripts' MVC pattern.

**EventEmitter.js**

```
export default class EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this._events = {};
    }

    static on(event, listener) {
        (this._events[event] || (this._events[event] = [])).push(listener);
        return this;
    }

    static emit(event, args) {
        (this._events[event] || []).slice().forEach(listener => listener(args));
    }
}
```

However, wherever I try to emit some events, it does not work as I get an error message:

> TypeError: (intermediate value).emit is not a function

This is how I want to emit my event from my **ModelClass.js**:

```
import EventEmitter from "../EventEmitter.js";
export default class ModelClass extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(options) {
        super();
        super.emit('test', options);
    }
```

Please note that I do not want to call the emit function like in above case, I have different methods inside the class where I want to emit my events, but for easier understanding I put it here, because it even does not work in the constructor.

Comment: You made your `emit` *static*, that's probably the problem - why not use standard methods?

Comment: oh shoot! This could be it! I put static there because I was debugging my initial issues with emitter, but somehow on the way I probably fixed the initial issue, but the 'static'keyword was still there ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your methods are `static`, so they're on `EventEmitter`, not *instances* of it. Remove `static` from `on` and `emit`.

---

A couple of side notes, FWIW:

- Normally you'd just use `this.emit()`, even if `emit` is defined by the parent class. No need for `super.emit()` unless you specifically want to bypass the `emit` defined at the current level (you aren't defining one, so...).
- It's generally best not to call methods from the constructor (because subclasses can override those methods, but won't have had a chance to complete their initialization yet), and certainly not to have the constructor perform an action like emitting an event. Just FWIW.
- You may also want to remove `emit` from `EventEmitter` (or leave it static), and instead have `ModelClass` call some internal emitter (or `EventEmitter.emit`). Otherwise, you make `emit` a public method of `ModelClass` which means any *consumer* of it can emit events from it, which probably isn't ideal.

Again, just FWIW.

Comment: T.J. that was the issue yes. I previously had other issues with my event emitter, and I put static just to try and fix it. But along the way I fixed my initial issues but forgot to remove static from Emitter... consequence of 6 hour straight coding.. :/ THANKS! Will accept once it allows me to.